# Java 8 extracting/coverting List<Object> into Map<String, List<String>> using stream()

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Trying to figure out how can i use the new Java 8 feature .stream() in my code effectively.

Here is my code in general

```
List<Item> list = db.query(sqlStatement, (rs, i) -> new Item(rs));

    Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByName = new HashMap<>();

    for (Item m : list) {
        if (!itemsByName.containsKey(m.getName())) {

            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
                            items.add(m);

            itemsByName.put(m.getName(), items);
        } else {
            itemsByName.get(m.getName()).add(m);
        }
    }
```

By this (1)

```
List<Item> list = db.query(sqlStatement, (rs, i) -> new Item(rs));
```

I get the List of Items which looks like:

**list(0): Name1:Value1**

**list(1): Name1:Value2**

**list(2): Name2:Value1**

**list(3): Name3:Value3**

By this (2)

```
Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByName = new HashMap<>();

    for (Item m : list) {
        if (!itemsByName.containsKey(m.getName())) {

            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
                            items.add(m);

            itemsByName.put(m.getName(), items);
        } else {
            itemsByName.get(m.getName()).add(m);
        }
    }
```

I want to get:

**MapKey(Name1): List{Name1:Value1, Name1:Value2}**

**MapKey(Name2): List{Name2:Value1}**

**MapKey(Name3): List{Name3:Value3}**

*How to rewrite code (2) using the stream() to get the same result?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be implementing the standard "group by" primitive. This is supported out-of-the-box by the Streams API:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByName = 
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName));
```

Comment: Wow! So easy! I paid more time to write this question. Thank you.